# Handle f1 key pressed in an invisible form

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I had to set the startup form from a Windows form application to be entirely invisible for the users and then to handle the f1 key press event.

I set the form invisible using the following code:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    base.SetVisibleCore(false);
}
```

Then I noticed that the HelpRequestedEvent is not called anymore... So the following code is never called...

```
this.HelpRequested += (sender, eventArgs) => { MessageBox.Show("Hi"); };
```

The above code was added in the constructor of the form. I am now trying to keep the form entirely invisible (as it is with the overridden version of `SetCoreVisibility`) and also handle this `HelpRequested` event, is there a way how to do this ?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to display help for a completely invisible UI.  Move it to a form that actually *is* visible.  Seeing the F1 key is technically possible, implement IMessageFilter.

Comment: Thank you for reply ! The form is triggering behind the scene some new threads that are doing some operations, and this should be a form since it gets integrated into another app and so on... Do you somehow know a quick example / tutorial of the IMessageFiler usage ?

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea to hijack a user pressing the `F1` key for your application when it might be pertinent to the active application.

Comment: That makes even less sense, surely it is the "other app" that should be responsible for responding to help requests.

Comment: Actually the cursor is changing its shape in the UI after the invisible form is getting in action, that is the only clue that now the user is using the loaded app instead of the main one. What can i say more... i just need a solution for this, i cannot rewrote the hole system just to have a well done design app...

Comment: I implemented the IMessageFilter and add the class which implemented this interface in my Main method before the "Application.Run(myForm)" like "Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyMessageFilter());" Any way in the "PreFilterMessage" method i added a break point just on its entry and the break point was never hit when the form was invisible, it was hit only when the form was visible. So i consider that this is not a "working" solution in this context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Timer and check the Keyboard for F1:

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F1))
    {
        // do your stuff..
    } 
}
```

For this to work in  a WinForms programm you need to include references to 'PresentationCore' and 'WindowsBase' and also include `using System.Windows.Input;`

A bit of a hack, imo. And I won't reiterate on the issue of how a user, not seeing anything, could expect there is hope of achieving anything by pressing `F1`..

Comment: Thank you for the example ! When you mean a Timer, you mean a timer from the "System.Timers" namespace, also am i thinking right ? Should i set this timer to tick quite often to something like 0.1 seconds, in order to catch the F1 key down event ? Did i understood right ?

Comment: Yes, I tried a regular System.Timer. 100ms is probably fine, depending a little on the circumstances, like machine and workload..